# Command defined inside standalone file appears unavailable in main document

Tags: macros, standalone

In the file producing my `tikz`-graphic, I define a new command that creates a `tikzpicture` using particular arguments (left out in MWE below because the problem reproduces without those). I use the `standalone` class for the figure, so that I can more quickly develop the figure without recompiling my entire article, and without cluttering my directory with small files `\input`-ing the different figures. However, when I `\input` the standalone-file in my main document, I cannot execute the new command defined inside the standalone-file.

My standalone figure MWE file (called `stafig.tex`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\examplefig}[0]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (2, 1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\onlyifstandalone{
 \examplefig
 \examplefig
}

\end{document}
```

I include it in my MWE main article like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \input{stafig}
 \examplefig
 \caption{Yes, a test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The standalone-file compiles fine and has the expected result. However, compiling the main file fails with:

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.8  \examplefig
```

In my real case, I want to use this macro to create four plots in different subfloat-environments with different parameters.

My questions:

- Why is compilation of the main file failing? Is this expected?
- How could I approach this instead?
- How would I do if I additionally use `pgfkeys`?

Comment: BTW, you should avoid empty lines inside the `document` environment of the standalone file. They create a paragraph break, which will set the width to `\linewidth`, which is not wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update 2011/12/21

I now release `standalone` v1.0 which has a new *package* option `group` (=`true`|`false`) which can be used to switch of the normally added group using `group=false`. The patches below are therefore not necessary any longer and should not be used with v1.0. (This can be tested using `\makeatletter\@ifpackagelater{2011/12/21}{<v1.0>}{<older>}\makeatother`.)

---

#### Original answer:

If a `standalone` file is included using the `standalone` package and `\input` its content is placed inside a group, therefore the macro definition is only done local and does no longer exists afterwards. This is by design, but I might add a package option to suppress it in the next version.

You could work around this by defining the macro globally instead. For this use `\gdef\examplefig` instead of `\newcommand{\examplefig}` (or `\newcommand{\examplefig}[0]`).

---

You can also use the following patch for the `standalone` package (v0.4a) which removes the group around the file. However, this might break one the package gets updated and is not tested with nested standalone files (i.e. standalone files which `\input` other standalone files).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@document\document
\let\orig@enddocument\enddocument
\def\sa@document{%
  \endgroup
  \global\let\enddocument\sa@enddocument
  \sa@atbegindocument
}
\def\sa@enddocument{%
  \sa@atenddocument
  \global\let\document\orig@document
  \global\let\enddocument\orig@enddocument
  \begingroup
  \@ignoretrue
  \def\@currenvir{document}%
  \aftergroup\endinput
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \input{stafig}
 \centering
 \examplefig
 \caption{Yes, a test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand and your solution works... for the **MWE**, that is. Not shown in my **MWE**, I'm using `pgfkeys` in my real situation, and those keys are also local (that's at least my conclusion from `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/photontest' and I am going to ignore it`) :(. Can I somehow make global what `pgfkeys` defines? (Meta-Q: Should I open a new question for this, alter the current one, or leave this Q as a comment?)

Comment: @gerrit: The comment is fine at the moment. You could edit the question as well if you want. Also, not need to have MWE always in bold. It is complicated to make PGF keys global. I would rather remove the group instead. See my updated answer for a patch. I note this down as a feature request for the package.